# Cannot authenticate to GKE cluster using python kubernetes module (ERROR:root:fileno)

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to authenticate to GKE using Python's Kubernetes module.

After running

```
from kubernetes import config
from kubernetes.client import Configuration

config.load_kube_config() # tried config.load_config() as well
```

I get a cryptic `ERROR:root:fileno` error.

`Configuration().get_default_copy().host` confirms that the host is picked up from the config file.   The issue is with the user section.

When trying to use the API I get `User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource...`

I have followed all the steps to install `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`.

From CLI, this config works just fine to fetch info from the GKE cluster (pod name, execute cmd, etc...)

Below is the `users` block within the config

```
users:
- name: project_region_cluster1
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
      installHint: Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following
        https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
      provideClusterInfo: true
```

Comment: No.  Unfortunately I did not and had to move away from using this module.